Pepper Robot, issues while retrieving data via php query from Altervista
i'm a University student and i'm working on a project originally made in 2021 by my university group. The project is based on a website where users can write stories and an app where stories are listed and can be told by Pepper. Now i need to take this project again and add new functionalities, but i'm having troubles when i try to retrieve data from the PHP query. PHP queries are stored in Altervista shared space where is also stored and handled the project database (Altervista includes phpMyAdmin).
In the inithial development in 2021 we had no issue trying to retrieve query results from Altervista to the Pepper app, but now, using the same code, i'm having troubles.
Follows one of the classes in the project, in this class I only need to get all the story titles in order to make them visible in the app story list.
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GetTitles extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    Context context;
    protected static ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public GetTitles(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL ("https://pepper4storytelling.altervista.org/Cartella%20temporanea%20GETTERS/story_list.php");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
            for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++ ) {
                JSONObject ob = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                titleList.add(i, ob.get("Titolo").toString());
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

}

As you can see, it doesn't seem to be a query issue, since the query effectively returns values in a JSON object.
[{"Titolo":"TESTVIDEOPICCOLO","Username":"pieeerpaolo","Data pubblicazione":"2024-03-24 22:54:42"},{"Titolo":"PROVAVIDEO","Username":"nadja65","Data pubblicazione":"2024-02-08 14:34:48"},{"Titolo":"Preparare lo zaino per la scuola","Username":"nadja65","Data pubblicazione":"2023-01-17 11:03:04"},{"Titolo":"I tre porcellini","Username":"Vincenzo","Data pubblicazione":"2021-11-04 11:42:01"},{"Titolo":"orientamento prova","Username":"nadja65","Data pubblicazione":"2022-04-26 11:49:06"},{"Titolo":"Orientamento DIB","Username":"giovill","Data pubblicazione":"2022-04-26 14:43:18"},{"Titolo":"Mangiare bene, Vivere meglio","Username":"davide_46","Data pubblicazione":"2023-05-09 16:48:29"},{"Titolo":"La Piramide Alimentare","Username":"Dav99ide","Data pubblicazione":"2023-05-22 14:52:53"},{"Titolo":"Scambio di Robot","Username":"nadja65","Data pubblicazione":"2023-09-29 16:14:49"},{"Titolo":"Prova storia video","Username":"Enzo","Data pubblicazione":"2022-10-07 12:34:15"},{"Titolo":"Prova audio","Username":"Enzo","Data pubblicazione":"2022-10-07 14:20:19"},{"Titolo":"Antonino e il suo pentolino_1","Username":"daniela71","Data pubblicazione":"2023-05-06 20:10:49"},{"Titolo":"Il re","Username":"enzo","Data pubblicazione":"2022-12-01 13:27:07"},{"Titolo":"La storia della farfalla","Username":"enzo","Data pubblicazione":"2022-12-01 13:46:16"},{"Titolo":"La Spesa","Username":"enzo","Data pubblicazione":"2022-12-01 14:04:30"},{"Titolo":"Il mondo dei Verdotti","Username":"Dav99ide","Data pubblicazione":"2023-05-19 10:40:02"},{"Titolo":"La Fata Smemorina","Username":"Dav99ide","Data pubblicazione":"2023-05-19 10:53:47"},{"Titolo":"Io sono il Pepper Sbagliato","Username":"nadja65","Data pubblicazione":"2023-09-29 16:52:50"},{"Titolo":"Antonino e il suo pentolino","Username":"daniela71","Data pubblicazione":"2023-10-21 11:14:12"},{"Titolo":"GIORNATA ORIENTAMENTO DIB","Username":"nadja65","Data pubblicazione":"2024-02-06 12:33:02"},{"Titolo":"Il Viaggio delle Forchette Magiche","Username":"pieeerpaolo","Data pubblicazione":"2024-02-06 12:33:34"},{"Titolo":"Biancaneve","Username":"Vincenzo","Data pubblicazione":"2021-11-09 13:07:42"},{"Titolo":"Il leone e lo scoiattolo","Username":"Pepper123","Data pubblicazione":"2021-11-17 15:30:34"},{"Titolo":"Il Cavaliere Anticovid","Username":"nadja65","Data pubblicazione":"2022-01-13 16:21:41"},{"Titolo":"Pepper dice no alla Guerra","Username":"nadja65","Data pubblicazione":"2022-02-28 13:27:46"},{"Titolo":"Il bruco e la farfalla","Username":"Vincenzo","Data pubblicazione":"2021-10-06 12:45:38"},{"Titolo":"Storia con Domande","Username":"Vincenzo","Data pubblicazione":"2024-05-06 16:52:21"}]

App Manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="esame.pepper">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PepperStory"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity android:name=".GetStory"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
    </application>

    <uses-feature android:name="com.softbank.hardware.pepper"/>
</manifest>

build.gradle (:app)

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "esame.pepper"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: \["\*.jar"\])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.7'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.aldebaran:qisdk:1.7.5'
implementation 'com.aldebaran:qisdk-design:1.7.5'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

}

I suspect that the issue lies with Pepper and the fact that it hasn't been updated in years. Both Pepper Emulator and real Pepper have this issue, but if i try to run the app on a different emulator, all the queries work fine, and I can retrieve all the required data.
As you can see in the following screenshots, when using the Pepper emulator, I'm unable to load the story titles.
Pepper Emulator
In this case, the try-catch block fails, indicating that there is an issue with receiving the data from the query.
But if I use another emulator created with the AVD Manager, the query work, and I can see the story titles.
Other Emulator not directly related to Pepper
Note for Pepper Emulator, directly taken from the official intallation guide
Windows only
To ensure compatibility, Emulator.29.0.11 is automatically installed.
Android Studio version

Android Studio 4.0
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223, built on May 20, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_412-412-b08 x86
VM: OpenJDK Server VM by OpenLogic-OpenJDK
Windows 11 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 742M
Cores: 12
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.softbank.robot.sdkplugin

Systems used

Desktop with windows 11 and Intel i5-11400 CPU
Laptop with Windows 10 and Intel i5-5200U CPU

Both systems produce the same result. Additionally, in both systems, i can access Pepper Emulator only if i run the 32-bit executable. If I try to run the emulator in Android Studio 64-bit, it crashes instantly.
Honestly, I don't know if the executable thing could be the cause of the whole issue, but when we created this project, I mostly worked on the website side, so I'm a bit lost right now.
I apologize for this lengthy post, but I tried to include all the valuable information for understanding my issue.
Thanks in advance to anyone who will consider helping me.

I've kind of solved the issue; it's not the best solution, but I can't do much more. I can't update the Pepper SDK since it hasn't been updated in years, and on the website side, the only thing I can do is disable HTTPS and serve the entire site over HTTP. For the solution, I used OkHttpClient, which allows you to create custom HTTP requests. With this, I managed to make the requests work again. As I said, it's not the best solution, but if you're having similar trouble, try using OkHttpClient.

Without any logs it's a bit hard to say for sure but since I had a similar issue the other day it maybe of help to you or others.
The problem you are having is probably related to the Let's Encrypt Chain of Trust ([1], [2]) shortening.
My issue was, that I couldn't access any resources/sites (in this case, images to display on the tablet) if the site used a Let's Encrypt certificate (your site pepper4storytelling.altervista.org seems to be using one as well).
The exception in my case was javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.. It was somewhat concealed since it was logged as info and not as an error. Based on this exception I found this SO post. With that post I created the following helper class that creates an OkHttpClient that also includes the new and valid certificates.
/**
 * PotentiallyUnsafeCustomOkHttpClient is a utility class that provides a method to create an OkHttpClient with additional certificates.
 * IMPORTANT: IF ONE OF THESE CERTIFICATES EXPIRES, ALL CERTIFICATES ARE ACCEPTED AGAIN, WHICH IS WHY WE ARE THEN VULNERABLE TO MITM ATTACKS.
 * This is needed for Android versions of 6 and below (maybe even including 7/API lvl 25) to fix the SSLHandshakeException with Let's Encrypt certificates.
 * See https://letsencrypt.org/2023/07/10/cross-sign-expiration for more information.
 * THESE ARE ONLY VALID UNTIL 2030-06-04 (ISRG Root X1) AND 2035-09-04 (ISRG Root X2). AFTER THAT, THE CERTIFICATES NEED TO BE UPDATED.
 * (Running android 6 in 2035.. godspeed, soldier)
 */
class PotentiallyUnsafeCustomOkHttpClient {
    companion object {
        private const val isrgRootX1 = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
                "MIIFazCCA1OgAwIBAgIRAIIQz7DSQONZRGPgu2OCiwAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw\n" +
                "TzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxKTAnBgNVBAoTIEludGVybmV0IFNlY3VyaXR5IFJlc2Vh\n" +
                "cmNoIEdyb3VwMRUwEwYDVQQDEwxJU1JHIFJvb3QgWDEwHhcNMTUwNjA0MTEwNDM4\n" +
                "WhcNMzUwNjA0MTEwNDM4WjBPMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEpMCcGA1UEChMgSW50ZXJu\n" +
                "ZXQgU2VjdXJpdHkgUmVzZWFyY2ggR3JvdXAxFTATBgNVBAMTDElTUkcgUm9vdCBY\n" +
                "MTCCAiIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggIPADCCAgoCggIBAK3oJHP0FDfzm54rVygc\n" +
                "h77ct984kIxuPOZXoHj3dcKi/vVqbvYATyjb3miGbESTtrFj/RQSa78f0uoxmyF+\n" +
                "0TM8ukj13Xnfs7j/EvEhmkvBioZxaUpmZmyPfjxwv60pIgbz5MDmgK7iS4+3mX6U\n" +
                "A5/TR5d8mUgjU+g4rk8Kb4Mu0UlXjIB0ttov0DiNewNwIRt18jA8+o+u3dpjq+sW\n" +
                "T8KOEUt+zwvo/7V3LvSye0rgTBIlDHCNAymg4VMk7BPZ7hm/ELNKjD+Jo2FR3qyH\n" +
                "B5T0Y3HsLuJvW5iB4YlcNHlsdu87kGJ55tukmi8mxdAQ4Q7e2RCOFvu396j3x+UC\n" +
                "B5iPNgiV5+I3lg02dZ77DnKxHZu8A/lJBdiB3QW0KtZB6awBdpUKD9jf1b0SHzUv\n" +
                "KBds0pjBqAlkd25HN7rOrFleaJ1/ctaJxQZBKT5ZPt0m9STJEadao0xAH0ahmbWn\n" +
                "OlFuhjuefXKnEgV4We0+UXgVCwOPjdAvBbI+e0ocS3MFEvzG6uBQE3xDk3SzynTn\n" +
                "jh8BCNAw1FtxNrQHusEwMFxIt4I7mKZ9YIqioymCzLq9gwQbooMDQaHWBfEbwrbw\n" +
                "qHyGO0aoSCqI3Haadr8faqU9GY/rOPNk3sgrDQoo//fb4hVC1CLQJ13hef4Y53CI\n" +
                "rU7m2Ys6xt0nUW7/vGT1M0NPAgMBAAGjQjBAMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBBjAPBgNV\n" +
                "HRMBAf8EBTADAQH/MB0GA1UdDgQWBBR5tFnme7bl5AFzgAiIyBpY9umbbjANBgkq\n" +
                "hkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAgEAVR9YqbyyqFDQDLHYGmkgJykIrGF1XIpu+ILlaS/V9lZL\n" +
                "ubhzEFnTIZd+50xx+7LSYK05qAvqFyFWhfFQDlnrzuBZ6brJFe+GnY+EgPbk6ZGQ\n" +
                "3BebYhtF8GaV0nxvwuo77x/Py9auJ/GpsMiu/X1+mvoiBOv/2X/qkSsisRcOj/KK\n" +
                "NFtY2PwByVS5uCbMiogziUwthDyC3+6WVwW6LLv3xLfHTjuCvjHIInNzktHCgKQ5\n" +
                "ORAzI4JMPJ+GslWYHb4phowim57iaztXOoJwTdwJx4nLCgdNbOhdjsnvzqvHu7Ur\n" +
                "TkXWStAmzOVyyghqpZXjFaH3pO3JLF+l+/+sKAIuvtd7u+Nxe5AW0wdeRlN8NwdC\n" +
                "jNPElpzVmbUq4JUagEiuTDkHzsxHpFKVK7q4+63SM1N95R1NbdWhscdCb+ZAJzVc\n" +
                "oyi3B43njTOQ5yOf+1CceWxG1bQVs5ZufpsMljq4Ui0/1lvh+wjChP4kqKOJ2qxq\n" +
                "4RgqsahDYVvTH9w7jXbyLeiNdd8XM2w9U/t7y0Ff/9yi0GE44Za4rF2LN9d11TPA\n" +
                "mRGunUHBcnWEvgJBQl9nJEiU0Zsnvgc/ubhPgXRR4Xq37Z0j4r7g1SgEEzwxA57d\n" +
                "emyPxgcYxn/eR44/KJ4EBs+lVDR3veyJm+kXQ99b21/+jh5Xos1AnX5iItreGCc=\n" +
                "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
        private const val isrgRootX2 = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" +
                "MIICGzCCAaGgAwIBAgIQQdKd0XLq7qeAwSxs6S+HUjAKBggqhkjOPQQDAzBPMQsw\n" +
                "CQYDVQQGEwJVUzEpMCcGA1UEChMgSW50ZXJuZXQgU2VjdXJpdHkgUmVzZWFyY2gg\n" +
                "R3JvdXAxFTATBgNVBAMTDElTUkcgUm9vdCBYMjAeFw0yMDA5MDQwMDAwMDBaFw00\n" +
                "MDA5MTcxNjAwMDBaME8xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMSkwJwYDVQQKEyBJbnRlcm5ldCBT\n" +
                "ZWN1cml0eSBSZXNlYXJjaCBHcm91cDEVMBMGA1UEAxMMSVNSRyBSb290IFgyMHYw\n" +
                "EAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEACIDYgAEzZvVn4CDCuwJSvMWSj5cz3es3mcFDR0HttwW\n" +
                "+1qLFNvicWDEukWVEYmO6gbf9yoWHKS5xcUy4APgHoIYOIvXRdgKam7mAHf7AlF9\n" +
                "ItgKbppbd9/w+kHsOdx1ymgHDB/qo0IwQDAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwDwYDVR0T\n" +
                "AQH/BAUwAwEB/zAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUfEKWrt5LSDv6kviejM9ti6lyN5UwCgYIKoZI\n" +
                "zj0EAwMDaAAwZQIwe3lORlCEwkSHRhtFcP9Ymd70/aTSVaYgLXTWNLxBo1BfASdW\n" +
                "tL4ndQavEi51mI38AjEAi/V3bNTIZargCyzuFJ0nN6T5U6VR5CmD1/iQMVtCnwr1\n" +
                "/q4AaOeMSQ+2b1tbFfLn\n" +
                "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"

        fun createClientWithAdditionalCerts(
            connectTimeout: Long = 10,
            readTimeout: Long = 10,
            writeTimeout: Long = 10
        ): OkHttpClient {
            val okHttpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 25) {
                    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                    val isgRootX1ExpiryDate = dateFormat.parse("2030-06-04").time
                    val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

                    if (currentTime < isgRootX1ExpiryDate) {
                        val cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
                        val isgRootX1Certificate =
                            cf.generateCertificate(
                                isrgRootX1.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8).inputStream()
                            )
                        val isgRootX2Certificate =
                            cf.generateCertificate(
                                isrgRootX2.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8).inputStream()
                            )

                        val certificates = HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
                            .addTrustedCertificate(isgRootX1Certificate as X509Certificate)
                            .addTrustedCertificate(isgRootX2Certificate as X509Certificate)
                            .addPlatformTrustedCertificates() // to trust system certificates as well, performance impact may be present and needs to be tested
                            .build()

                        okHttpClientBuilder
                            .sslSocketFactory(
                                certificates.sslSocketFactory(),
                                certificates.trustManager
                            )
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "CERTIFICATES EXPIRED, FALLING BACK TO UNSECURE CONNECTION")
                        // create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
                        val trustAllCerts: Array<TrustManager> = arrayOf(object : X509TrustManager {
                            override fun checkClientTrusted(
                                chain: Array<out X509Certificate>?,
                                authType: String?
                            ) {
                            }

                            override fun checkServerTrusted(
                                chain: Array<out X509Certificate>?,
                                authType: String?
                            ) {
                            }

                            override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate> = arrayOf()
                        })

                        // use the all-trusting trust manager
                        val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
                        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, SecureRandom())

                        // create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
                        val sslSocketFactory = sslContext.socketFactory
                        if (trustAllCerts.isNotEmpty() && trustAllCerts.first() is X509TrustManager) {
                            okHttpClientBuilder.sslSocketFactory(
                                sslSocketFactory,
                                trustAllCerts.first() as X509TrustManager
                            )
                        }
                    }

                    okHttpClientBuilder
                        .connectTimeout(connectTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(readTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(writeTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                }

                return okHttpClientBuilder.build()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                return okHttpClientBuilder.build()
            }
        }
    }
}

